# Find next Aloha Number

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

I found this problem in one of coding practice sites...Problem goes as below.

A number is said to be an **aloha number** if it is comprises entirely of 4s and 7s. Below are few examples of **Aloha Numbers**

- **4477**
- **47744477**

Your program will get an integer number of a non Aloha Number and your output must return the next Aloha number (**in the form of string**) for that input.

**Example 1**

Input : **1234**

Output: **4444**

**Example 2**

Input : **4472**

Output: **4474**

- Input number represent the integer between 1 and 2*(10^9)
- Input number is not Aloha Number

I tried to solve this problem as below..

```
- (NSString *) nextAlohaNumber:(NSUInteger) number{

        // method convertNumberIntoDigit return a array of digits present in input number
        NSMutableArray *numberDigits = [self convertNumberIntoDigit:number];
        NSUInteger tempNum;

        for(int index = 0; index < numberDigits.count; index++){
            tempNum = [[numberDigits objectAtIndex:index] intValue];
            if(4 != tempNum && 7 != tempNum){
                if(4 > tempNum){
                    [numberDigits replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
                }else if (7 > tempNum){
                    [numberDigits replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7]];
                }
                else if(7 < tempNum){
                    [numberDigits replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
                    int previousIndex = index-1;
                    int previousNum = [[numberDigits objectAtIndex:previousIndex] integerValue];
                    if(previousIndex ){
                        if(4 == previousNum){
                            [numberDigits replaceObjectAtIndex:previousIndex withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7]];
                        }
                        else if(7 == previousNum){
                            [numberDigits replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return [self numberArrayToStr:numberDigits]; // convert strings with digit in Array
    }
```

But this method doesn't pass all the test cases, for example it fails on input 4478, 790 etc.
Can any one please help me to solve this problem for all inputs with better time and space complexity.

PS: I'm ok with C,C++ code as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your code does not work and you need someone to write you code that does. That is not what SO is for, I'm afraid. (In addition, your code is neither C nor C++.)

Comment: That looks like Objective-C. Please update your tags.

Comment: @Jongware & E_net4 I know guys this code is in Objective-C cause I wrote this and I don't want any body to write any sort of code for me..I have already wrote some.It's not working for some particular cases that's I'm just asking people to suggest on those cases. and I think this place is all out that, isn't it?

Comment: Well, your error seems to be you forget to add 1 to the digit on the left when changing a digit >7 into a 4. You should do that *before* testing if it's a 4 or 7 (and you do not need a separate test, as it will be picked up in the next loop iteration).

Comment: Thanks @Jongware for your informative comments...you're right I forgot to add one digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite my comment above, I wondered about the "time and space complexity". It turned out to be trivial; this only takes 3 long integer variables and a single loop over each input digit (which can be incremented by this algorithm to use 1 more digit; and this will not cause an integer overflow).

Starting from the lowest digit, if it's lower than `4` replace it with `4`. If it's lower than `7`, replace it with `7`. For `8` and `9`, replace it with `4` and increment the *next* digit. Repeat until all digits are processed.

The following code returns the number itself for a proper "aloha" number, the next higher if not.

It requires `long` variables (using more than 32 bits), because the aloha number for the largest allowed input, 2*(10^9), is `4444444444` -- outside the range of a 32-bit integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    long not_aloha, aloha, digit;
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf ("please give an aloha number\n");
        return -1;
    }
    not_aloha = atoi (argv[1]);
    printf ("not aloha: %ld\n", not_aloha);

    aloha = 0;
    digit = 1;
    while (not_aloha)
    {
        if ( (not_aloha % 10) <= 4)
            aloha += 4*digit;
        else if ( (not_aloha % 10 ) <= 7)
            aloha += 7*digit;
        else
        {
            aloha += 4*digit;
            not_aloha += 10;
        }
        digit *= 10;
        not_aloha /= 10;
    }
    printf ("aloha: %ld\n", aloha);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would give wrong answer for 15 i.e. 47 instead of 44.